# How can I convert several makrdown files to pdf?

Tags: latex, markdown

I wrote a lot of markdown files. I would like to convert them all into a one single PDF file, like you do when you use overleaf and latex.

I would like something like this:

```
# Title 1
/input{file1.md}

# Title 2
/input{file2.md}

## Title 2.1
/input{file3.md}
```

And have a complete markdown file using other file, to then convert it to a single PDF file.

Comment: maybe have a look at `\markdownInput{...}` from  https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks! that is interesting.